# No email content with Mail::IMAPClient

Tags: windows, perl, imap

This is how I connect yo GMail using `Mail::IMAPClient`

```
sub connectGMail
{
    my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new
    (  
       PeerAddr => 'imap.gmail.com',  
       PeerPort => 993, 
       SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE
    )  
    or die "socket(): $@";  

    my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new
    (
        User     => 'whateverUser',
        Password => 'aG00dP455w0rd'
        Socket   => $socket
    )
    or die "Cannot connect  ($@)\n";
    return $client;
}
```

Then I pass this client object to `processEmails` subroutine

```
sub processEmails
{
    my $client = shift;

    if ($client->IsAuthenticated())
    {
        $client->select('Pruebas');
        my @messages = $client->messages();
        my $mime_parser = getMIMEParser();
        my $filer = MIME::Parser::FileInto->new();
        mkdir(EXTRACT_DIR);

        for(@messages)
        {
            my $msg_body = $client->message_string($_);
            my $msg_subject = Encode::decode('MIME-Header', $client->subject($_));
            if ($msg_body)
            {
                my $dir = EXTRACT_DIR . "/" . $msg_subject;
                $filer->init($dir);
                mkdir($dir);
                $mime_parser->filer($filer);
                my $ok = parseEmail($mime_parser, $msg_body);
                if ($ok)
                {
                    print(STDERR "Email \"$msg_subject\" parsed OK\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print(STDERR "No body for message with subject $msg_subject\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print(STDERR "Something nasty happened\n");
    }
}
```

The problem is that `$msg_body` (retreived using [`message_string`](https://metacpan.org/module/Mail%3a%3aIMAPClient#message_string)) is empty for all messages, but `$msg_subject` is correct, which means the connection is OK. Here's the output:

```
No body for message with subject íQuÚ pasa!
No body for message with subject Prueba con formateo HTML
```

Comment: try `$client->body_string($_)` instead of `message_string()`

Comment: That works, but I need the headers too to parse it with `MIME::Parser`. The title is confusing, I edited it.

Comment: I don't know what `getMIMEParser()` and `parseEmail()` are doing. Have you looked at the `parse_headers()` method in `Mail::IMAPClient`?

Comment: But I need to parse the whole email, not only the header, otherwise I won't get the attachements. This works fine in Linux btw (without even handling the Socket on the connection).

Comment: Add Debug=>1 parameter to Mail::IMAPClient->new to get transcript of IMAP session. It should help to locate problem (wrong IMAP command, wrong IMAP reply, wrong handling of IMAP reply).

Comment: I have had great success with Mail::Box and its sub-modules with retrieving emails and attachments. Did you look into using that?

Comment: @imran I don't see anything related to attachements, multipart and MIME in Mail::Box... http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Mail-Box-2.107/lib/Mail/Box-Overview.pod http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Mail-Box-2.107/lib/Mail/Box/Message.pod Can you please point to some use examples? My knowledge about emails is quite limited I'm afraid...

Comment: @m0skit0 looks like Mail::Box does not support encrypted IMAP connections so it may not be the right choice for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think it would be really helpful if you try to include a runnable code sample.

I changed your code a little and for me it works just perfectly fine. I have very similar code in my code base.

```
use Mail::IMAPClient;
use MIME::Parser::Filer;

my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    Server   => 'imap.gmail.com',
    User     => 'test@gmail.com',
    Password => 'test-pass',
    Ssl      => 1,
    Uid      => 1,
) or die "Cannot connect  ($@)\n";

$client->select('INBOX');
my @messages = $client->messages();
my $filer    = MIME::Parser::FileInto->new();
print "There are " . scalar @messages . " messages waiting.\n";

for (@messages) {
    print "Processing...\n";
    my $msg_body = $client->message_string($_);

    my $msg_subject = Encode::decode( 'MIME-Header', $client->subject($_) );
    if ($msg_body) {
        print "$msg_body\n";
        print( STDERR "Email \"$msg_subject\" parsed OK\n" );
    }
    else {
        print( STDERR "No body for message with subject $msg_subject\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll try to test this when I have time :)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and was able to fix it with:

`$client->Ignoresizeerrors(1)`